# Neo4j cypher query to search node having a relation with specific node and same relation with other node as well

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Referring to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv7rB.png), I have two categories of neo4j graph structure that I need to differentiate.

I have this logic to differentiate:

```
category 1 =>
Match (a:A)-[:A1]->(B)-[l1:B1]->(n1:C)
With n1, count(n1) as cnt, a Where cnt = 1 AND n1.id = "c"
Return a

category 2 =>
Match (a:A)-[:A1]->(B)-[l1:B1]->(n1:C)
With n1,count(n1) as cnt,a Where cnt>1 AND n1.id="c"
Return a
```

But this is not working for second category. Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point about aggregation in Neo4j, you can not have a count(n1), n1 ... would obviously always return "1" as the count.

Try this and you'll see the difference, the aggregation should be on a only ...

```
Match (a:A)-[:A1]->(B)-[l1:B1]->(n1:c)
WHERE n1.name = "c"
With count(n1) as cnt,a Where cnt>1
Return a
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

P.S. Your first query is also wrong for the same reason ...

**UPDATE** after you updated the image ...

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:A1]->(B)-[l1:B1]->(n1:C {id: "c"})
WITH a, count(*) AS cnt
WHERE cnt > 1
RETURN a, cnt;
```

That should do it ...

Comment: Thanks Tom, for pointing out this thing. That makes sense.
However, (sorry for this), there was something wrong with the previous image that i had added. I have updated the image.  
In the new scenario, i wont be able to separate them the way you pointed out.

Comment: And with those changes your queries make even less sense. What you're actually trying to distinguish is if there is one or multiple paths between C (with a given id, hence completely pointless to count it, there will always only be one !!!) and A, is that correct ?

Comment: I am trying to to count number of C nodes. And then if there is only one C node with "id:c" thats case 1, and if there is more than one C nodes, i am checking if it contains C node with "id:c" which makes case 2. 

As per your updated query, cnt will always be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as your math query, this matches any relationship with any nodes between them.

```js
Match (a:A)-[:A1*]->(n1:C)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Forgive me, but that will actually not work as you're specifying what the relationship type must be and B1 is not in there ... you can never reach A from C (or vice versa) that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TYPE(<relationship>)` function to check a relationships relation type. So `MATCH (a)-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c) WHERE TYPE(r1) = TYPE(r2) RETURN *` Will match all tuples where r1 and r2 are the same kind of relation.

You can then specify the relation direction as incoming (`(a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r2]-(c)`) or outgoing (`(a)<-[r1]-(b)-[r2]->(c)`)

Note: With Cypher, it insures that no node is revisited in a single pattern match, so you don't need to check that a is not c (`a <> c`)

```
// category 1 =>
MATCH ()-[r1]->(b:C)<-[r2]-()
WHERE TYPE(r1) = TYPE(r2)
WITH DISTINCT b
MATCH (a:A)-[*..25]->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT a

// category 1, known relation =>
MATCH ()-[r1:B1]->(b:C)<-[r2:B1]-()
WITH DISTINCT b
MATCH (a:A)-->()-->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT a

// category 2 =>
MATCH ()<-[r1]-(b:B)-[r2]->()
WHERE TYPE(r1) = TYPE(r2)
WITH DISTINCT b
MATCH (a:A)-[*..25]->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT a

// category 2, known relation =>
MATCH ()<-[r1:B1]-(b:B)-[r2:B1]->()
WITH DISTINCT b
MATCH (a:A)-->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT a
```